# KnockoutJS: Binding to objects with illegal names

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, knockout.js

The project I am working on requires alot of work with somewhat complex XML files, so I convert them into SimpleXML array, JSON Encode it and pass it to Knockout via Ajax.

The problem is that pretty much each property has attributes, which SimpleXML shoves into an object called `@attributes`. When I try to bind to it like `myObject().@attributes.Name`, I get an error

```
Message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL;
Bindings value: text: alertObj().@attributes.Name
```

I have tried `'@attributes', ['@attributes'], [@attributes]` but nothing is working. I have also tried various escape characters and unicode escapes.

This is what json looks like:

```
        var alertObject =
            {
                "@attributes":
                    {
                        "DescriptionContentType":"text\/plain",
                        "Description":"",
                        "IsActive":"true",
                        "Name":"Apache Requests Per Interval"
                    },
                "Frequency":
                    {
                        "PeriodInSeconds":"60"
                    },
                "MetricLevelNotification":"false",
                "AlertTriggerMode":"2",
                "CautionActionDelay":"0",
                "DangerActionDelay":"0",
                "CautionActionList":
                    {
                        "ActionID":
                            {
                                "ManagementModuleName":"Base Module",
                                "ConstructName":"Base SMTP Mail Action"
                            }
                    },
                "DangerActionList":
                    {
                        "ActionID":
                            {
                                "ManagementModuleName":"Base Module",
                                "ConstructName":"Base SMTP Mail Action"
                            }
                    },
                "MetricGroupingID":
                    {
                        "ManagementModuleName":"Base Module",
                        "ConstructName":"Apache Requests Per Interval"
                    },
                "AlertCombineOperator":"1",
                "AlertCompareOperator":"2",
                "CautionTargetValue":"2000",
                "DangerTargetValue":"15000",
                "CautionMinNumPerPeriod":"3",
                "CautionAlertPeriod":"6",
                "DangerMinNumPerPeriod":"1",
                "DangerAlertPeriod":"1"
            };
```

I would like to avoid altering structure and names in any way.

How can I get this to work??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because it is not a valid javascript variable name:

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode
>   categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”,
>   “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”,
>   or “Letter number (Nl)”.

from http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

A variable name cannot begin with a @ and hence you see the error. There is no point in appending single quotes, brackets or anything else. The variable name simply isn't valid and you need to change the way the data is returned from server.

Comment: This makes sense. I will alter the array on server side before json encording it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, and I totally agree that you should definitely change the way the data is returned from the server. However, if you really have no control over the data or cannot affect it for the moment, you might be able to render what you want using:

```
$data['@attributes'].Name
```